# Timers in C# with Global variables?

Tags: c#, timer, global-variables

I have a few issues with the code below.

When the application runs, as soon as `LookingAwayResult.Text = "Yes"`, the timer starts and counts to 10. When `LookingAwayResult.Text = "No"` or `"Maybe"`, the timer should stop and reset back to 0 again, but this does not.

When the timer reaches 10, a message box appears which is what I want, but this will continue showing and spam my screen. The timer is meant to reset back to 0 after the message box appears and the application to freeze until "Ok" is selected on the message box.

It seems like my code is looping all the timer which is not what I want.

```
private void OnFaceFrameArrived(object sender, FaceFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    // Retrieve the face reference
    FaceFrameReference faceRef = e.FrameReference;

    if (faceRef == null) return;

    // Acquire the face frame
    using (FaceFrame faceFrame = faceRef.AcquireFrame())
    {
        if (faceFrame == null) return;

        // Retrieve the face frame result
        FaceFrameResult frameResult = faceFrame.FaceFrameResult;

        // Display the values
        HappyResult.Text = frameResult.FaceProperties[FaceProperty.Happy].ToString();
        EngagedResult.Text = frameResult.FaceProperties[FaceProperty.Engaged].ToString();
        GlassesResult.Text = frameResult.FaceProperties[FaceProperty.WearingGlasses].ToString();
        LeftEyeResult.Text = frameResult.FaceProperties[FaceProperty.LeftEyeClosed].ToString();
        RightEyeResult.Text = frameResult.FaceProperties[FaceProperty.RightEyeClosed].ToString();
        MouthOpenResult.Text = frameResult.FaceProperties[FaceProperty.MouthOpen].ToString();
        MouthMovedResult.Text = frameResult.FaceProperties[FaceProperty.MouthMoved].ToString();


        //initilize look away timer for 10 seconds
        Timer lookAwayTimer = new Timer(interval: 10000);

        //inialize the poll tiomer for 50 ms
        Timer pollTimer = new Timer(interval: 50);


        LookingAwayResult.Text = frameResult.FaceProperties[FaceProperty.LookingAway].ToString();

        //if 10 seconds expires then show message box
        lookAwayTimer.Elapsed += (s, f) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Looking is set to yes", "Looking Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        };

        //enable poll timer
        pollTimer.Enabled = true;

        //check if person is looking. If they are not then enable the lookAwayTimer.  If they start looking
        //then disable the timer
        pollTimer.Elapsed += (s, f) =>
        {
            Check = frameResult.FaceProperties[FaceProperty.LookingAway].ToString();

            if (Check == "Yes")
            {
                lookAwayTimer.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                lookAwayTimer.Enabled = false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

What I am after is for the timer to be run after the person is not looking and stopped and reset back to 0 when the person is looking again.

When the timer has reached 10 seconds, the message box appears and the application freezes. The user has to select "Ok" for this box to disappear and the application to reset back to defaults.

From research, I believe maybe using a global variable or modal box would come in handy here?

I believe with a modal box this would freeze my application until the user does something with it? But this still does not solve my issues with the timer not resetting back to 0 and wanting the application to completely reset after "Ok" is selected.

I have also fond out that global variables in C# should be avoided unless necessary.

If a modal box is the answer for part of this, would I just change `MessageBox.Show` to `ShowDialog`?

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is clear  that you are not controlling any operation on click of buttons of message box.You might display the message box only for notifying to the user.

So to make your code not to pause while executing create the message box on a `different thread` so the execution will not be halted.

The following code creates a Message box on separate thread.

```
 public class ThreadIndependentMB
    {
        private readonly Dispatcher uiDisp;
        private readonly Window ownerWindow;

        public ThreadIndependentMB(Dispatcher UIDispatcher, Window owner)
        {
            uiDisp = UIDispatcher;
            ownerWindow = owner;
        }

        public MessageBoxResult Show(string msg, string caption="",
            MessageBoxButton buttons=MessageBoxButton.OK,
            MessageBoxImage image=MessageBoxImage.Information)
        {
            MessageBoxResult resmb = new MessageBoxResult();
            if (ownerWindow != null)
            uiDisp.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                resmb = MessageBox.Show(ownerWindow, msg, caption, buttons, image);

            }));
            else
                uiDisp.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    resmb = MessageBox.Show( msg, caption, buttons, image);

                }));
            return resmb;
        }


    }
```

Noe in your timer you can instantiate the class and call the Show method of that class.

Comment: How can I implement this code to do what I require with the timers also? What do I need to change?

Comment: Just make an object of the above class and call the show method of the class in elapsed event instead of MessageBox.Show()

Answer (score 0):

The [AutoReset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset(v=vs.110).aspx) property on the timer may solve your problem:

```
System.Timers.Timer lookAwayTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000)
{
    AutoReset = false
};

lookAwayTimer.Elapsed += (object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        pollTimer.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Looking is set to yes", "Looking Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        lookAwayTimer.Start();
        pollTimer.Start();
    };
```

Setting this to false will cause the timer to elapse once and then stop repeating (so it wont spam your screen) until you start it again - the default is true so it will keep auto resetting and calling this method every 10 seconds.

Comment: I have tried this and the message box keeps appearing :(

Comment: @lfctez Perhaps you should stop the poll timer as well? As this is still running and will re-enable the lookAwayTimer even though the message has popped up? I've updated my answer with a way you could do this.

Comment: Tried this and it is still the same sorry :(

Comment: No problem - all I can recommend then is putting this simple example into a new project and making sure it works like you expect and then trying to see where it differs from your project - good luck!.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. I'll give it a go!